# Algebraic Inequality involving AM-GM-HM

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

If $$a,b,c \;\epsilon \;R^+$$ 
Then show, $$\frac{bc}{b+c} + \frac{ab}{a+b} + \frac{ac}{a+c} \leq \frac{1}{2} \Bigl(a+b+c\Bigl)$$
I have solved a couple of problems using AM-GM but I have always struggled with selecting terms for the inequality.
I tried writing $a+b+c$ as $x$ and re-writing the inequality as $$\frac{bc}{x-a} + \frac{ab}{x-c} + \frac{ac}{x-b} \leq \frac{1}{2} \Bigl(x\Bigl)$$ 
This didn't help so instead I wrote it as $$2\Biggl(\frac {1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c}\Biggl ) \leq \frac{1}{2} \Bigl(a+b+c\Bigl)$$
Not sure what to to do next.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Remember that $HM(a, b)$ can also be written as $\dfrac {2ab}{a+b}$, which looks a lot like the LHS...

Comment: Oh, alright thank you so much.

Comment: @PrakharNagpal You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

## Proof

Just by $H_n \leq A_n$, we have

\begin{align*}
\frac{bc}{b+c} + \frac{ab}{a+b} + \frac{ac}{a+c}&=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{2}{\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}}+\frac{2}{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}}+\frac{2}{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{c}}\right)\\&\leq \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{b+c}{2}+\frac{a+b}{2}+\frac{a+c}{2}\right)\\&=\frac{a+b+c}{2}.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Multiply both sides by $4$ and rearrange:
$$\frac{bc}{b+c} + \frac{ab}{a+b} + \frac{ac}{a+c} \leq \frac{1}{2} \Bigl(a+b+c\Bigl) \Rightarrow \\
\left(a+b-\frac{4ab}{a+b}\right)+\left(b+c-\frac{4bc}{b+c}\right)+\left(c+a-\frac{4ca}{c+a}\right)\ge 0 \Rightarrow \\
\frac{(a-b)^2}{a+b}+\frac{(b-c)^2}{b+c}+\frac{(c-a)^2}{c+a}\ge 0.$$

Comment: +1 Nice, refreshing way to do it

Comment: @Ovi, thank you

Answer (score 0):

By C-S
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{bc}{b+c}\leq\sum_{cyc}\frac{bc}{(1+1)^2}\left(\frac{1^2}{b}+\frac{1^2}{c}\right)=\frac{a+b+c}{2.}$$